# Assigning to 'int *' from incompatible type 'value_type' (aka 'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >')

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector

Does anyone know how to call the vector pointer so that it can be assigned to an integer? Following is the code:

```
void floodFillwithColor(vector<vector<int>>* M, int x, int y, int newC){

    int* prevC = M[x][y];
    int* newCPtr = &newC;
    floodFillUtil(M, x, y, prevC, newCPtr);
};
```

Comment: `M` should probably be a reference, not a pointer. Also, C and C++ are different languages; only tag one.

Answer (score 2):

> how to call the vector pointer so that it can be assigned to an integer?

You cannot call a vector pointer, but you can use the indirection operator to get a reference to the pointed object, and then apply the subscript operator on that reference:

```
if(M)
    int some_value = (*M)[x][y]; // assign to an integer
else
    // handle the case where M is null
```

Comment: Great! that works! Is there a generalized rule for understanding anything related to pointers?

Comment: @JackReacher Define what you mean by _generalized rule for understanding anything related to pointers_.

Comment: @JackReacher No. Such generalized rule does not exist. But this will help you get started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: Any document which talks about a general way on how to use pointers for different types? May be, I am not able to put it rightly on what I mean.